# The Black Pawn's Revenge

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, path-finding, chess

**Objective**

The black pawn wants revenge. Plot out its last attack.

**Rules**

The black pawn (`L`) starts at the top row and moves downwards to the bottom row. Maximise points taken, indicating the path with `X`. Pawns (`P`) are 1, bishops (`B`) and knights (`N`) 3, rooks (`R`) 5, and queens (`Q`) 9. There won't be any kings in the input.

If there is more than one path that has the maximum amount of points, output any of those paths. There will not be any situations where the pawn cannot reach the bottom row.

**Examples**

Input:

```
----L---
-----P--
------P-
--R--P-Q
----P-P-
---P-P-P
--P-N---
-P------
```

Output:

```
----L---
-----X--
------X-
--R--P-X
----P-X-
---P-X-P
--P-X---
-P--X---
```

Input:

```
--L-----
-P------
P-------
-P------
P--Q----
-P------
P-------
-P------
```

Output:

```
--L-----
-PX-----
P-X-----
-PX-----
P--X----
-P-X----
P--X----
-P-X----
```

Comment: What should happen if the pawn can't reach the bottom row?

Comment: Actually, the text never says that it *has* to reach the bottom row. Is that the intention? Say, in the second example, would it be valid for the path to stop in the 5th row, after the pawn captured the queen?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Huh. I haven't actually thought of that. Yeah, the pawn should reach the bottom row. You can assume that any cases where the pawn can't reach the bottom row won't occur in the input.

Comment: And when it reaches the bottow row, it is promoted as a queen and kill everyone elese ...

Comment: What about El Passant?

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 332

```
def s(m,l,p):
 if not m:return 1
 b=m[0]+'-';z=filter(lambda i:(b[i]=='-')==(i==l),[l,l-1,l+1])
 if not z:return 0
 g=lambda i:s(m[1:],i,0)+[0,1,3,3,5,9]['-PBNRQ'.index(b[i])];i=max(z,key=g)
 if p:print m[0][:i]+'X'+m[0][i+1:];s(m[1:],i,p)
 return g(i)
import sys
t=sys.stdin.read().split('\n')
print t[0]
s(t[1:],t[0].index('L'),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>260 258 255 241 236</s> 222

```rb
->b{s=->l,w=p{c,*x=l.map &:dup
v=[1,3,3,5,9,0]['PBNRQ'.index(c[y=w||c.index(?L)])||5]
w&&c[y]=?X
(n=x[0])?(m=[]
[y-1,y,y+1].map{|z|(z==y)^(n[z]>?.)&&m<<s[x,z]}
q,r=m.max_by{|m|m ?m[0]:0}
q&&[q+v,c+r]):[v,c]}
s[b.lines][1]}
```

This program defines a function (`s`), which, given some board rows, returns the best path as a string, and the value in points of that path. `s` is recursive, so at each step it evaluates all possibilities and returns the best one.

Here's an online version with tests: http://ideone.com/6eMtm4

The readable version is available here: http://ideone.com/eoXUtp

All the steps I took to reduce the size of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/wolfascu/codegolf/commits/master/61005-the-black-pawns-revenge/61005-the-black-pawns-revenge-golfed.rb).